# Extracting data from a DateTime object

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm working on a method that can tell me if a certain date is within a certain period of dates. My method will have an argument of two DateTime objects; a start date and end date, and will be called by a DateTime object as well.

To play around with it, I've been trying to figure out how to extract the year, month, day , time, from a DateTime object that is being compared to. However I can't figure out how to get it going. I checked the API for DateTime, and the method it has to perform the function I want is monthOfYear().

But when I implement it, it outputs "Property[monthOfYear]".

The API places the method under DateTime.Property but I played around with that too and I'm not getting anywhere.

> ```
> import org.joda.time.DateTime;
>
>    public class Tester implements TesterInterface {
>
>        public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>            DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(2012, 5, 12, 13, 30);
>
>            System.out.println(dateTime1.monthOfYear());
>        }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`getMonthOfYear()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getMonthOfYear%28%29).

As [documented](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html):

> Each individual field can be queried in two ways:
>
> - getHourOfDay()
> - hourOfDay().get()

Comment: That did it. In the [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) it didn't list that method.

Comment: It actually does, as one of the inherited methods, search for it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
dateTime1.monthOfYear()
```

to

```
dateTime1.getMonthOfYear()
```